# How to restore connection on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need an auto-reconnect function in my app, but it doesn't work because iPhone itself does not reconnect when the connection is again available. You should switch iPhone off/on or switch apps to trigger it to connect. It doesn't work even in Safari, if the connection is lost. How can I do this from my app without switching app or shutting iPhone off/on?

Comment: What kind of connection? What classes do u use? Show some code...

Comment: Wifi connection. But it's about that iPhone itself does not reconnect.  The are the steps:
- start the app
- router off (iphone connection is lost)
- router on -> iphone don't try to restore connection if your app is still active

Comment: Now I see, just tested it with Safari and it doesn't reconnect. Check out Reachability API, i have heard good things about it.

Comment: Reachability also checks the connection of the iphone. I think, it can't trigger the iPhone to reconnect. I already tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the reachability api. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

you can find the ARC version of the same, [HERE](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

Reachability api posts a notification on the default center whenever the network status is changed. SO add yourself as the observer to this notification and do whatever you want when the network is back..!

A simple example from the same github page given above,

```
    // allocate a reachability object
    Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    // tell the reachability that we DONT want to be reachable on 3G/EDGE/CDMA
    reach.reachableOnWWAN = NO;

    // here we set up a NSNotification observer. The Reachability that caused the notification
    // is passed in the object parameter
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) 
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification 
                                               object:nil];

[reach startNotifier]
```